# Чи є якійсь відповідник до слова "забил" в українській мові?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Наприклад:

> Він останнім часом не дзвонить, тому й я ...

Можна мабуть сказати, *"тому й я перестав"*. Але чи є якійсь, так би мовити, більш молодіжний варіант?

Або:

> На этот предмет нельзя забивать.

Comment: Мабуть, це не молодіжний сленг, але *махнути рукою*.

Comment: Точно неформальний, але не певен, що молодіжний - *насрати*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Російсько-український народний сучасний словник (2009–дотепер) [пропонує](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) використовувати це слово без перекладу:

> 7. *(терять, потерять интерес, проигнорировать, покончить, вульг.)* забивати, забити:

Я вбачаю в цьому цілковитий сенс.

У значенні *"втратити зацікавленість, покінчити з, ігнорувати"* це слово утворилося як скорочення від *"забити болт"*. Болти, як відомо, закручуються викруткою, але якщо болт туго йде, його, фігурально кажучи, можна спробувати забити молотком, щоб швидко покінчити з цією роботою.

Окрім того, *болт* є евфемізмом до слова *"статевий член"*, що у даному випадку надає емоційної забарвленості, так само, як і інші словосполучення з цим словом.

---

Таким чином, слово *"забити"* цілком відповідає молодіжному стилю, а використання евфемізму замість вульгаризму відкриває шлях до ширших меж вжитку.

Answer (score 2):

російське "забей на это", я б переклав на українську як "залиш це". Що до вашого прикладу, то я б так переклав: "Він останнім часом не дзвонить, тому й я полишив наміри...". Далі, російське "На этот предмет нельзя забивать", переклав би: "Цей предмет не можна не брати до уваги".

Comment: В першому прикладі малось на увазі "тому й я перестав йому дзвонити", оскільки у нього не виникає зустрічного бажання. Мабуть можна сказати "тому й я полишив..." Стосовно другого прикладу, мався на увазі предмет, який вивчають в інституті тощо. І ваш варіант звучить достатньо ввічливо, в певному сенсі немолодіжно, формально. До речі я зрозумів що мене не стільки молодіжні, скільки якісь неформальні відповідники цікавили. В будь-якому разі дякую за ідеї.

Answer (score 2):

У різних ситуаціях можна вжити різні відповідники, наприклад:

1. *зістрибнути/зіскочити*
2. *попуститись* (чи це не з російської?)

Та найцікавішим відповідником мені здається слово *зневажити*. Уявіть собі цільову функцію ∑λ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>. Так ось, ми можемо сказати, що ми зневажили якійсь x<sub>j</sub>, якщо ми зменшили відповідну вагу λ<sub>j</sub>, інакше кажучи, припинили звертати на нього увагу, бо він для нас більше неважливий.

1. Я був надзвонював, але потім зістрибнув.
2. Цей предмет не можна зневажити.

Мені здається, що вживання слів як-от *зневажити* і *зістрибнути* краще передає значення *облишити* ніж це робить *забити*, бо згідно з походженням, яке розкрив у своєму пості bytebuster, *забити* це зробити нашвидкоруч чи неякісно, тоді як *зневажити* і *зістрибнути* це саме рідня для *облишити*, *дати спокій*, *відступитись*.